# Ordered field inequalities

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, field-theory, absolute-value

It's entirely possible these inequalities have been solved before but I can't easily find them by searching. This is Exercise 10 from page 83 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

**Exercise:**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

I've made almost no progress with these inequalities. For $(a)$, I was looking for a slick way to do it in one go, but couldn't find anything, so I thought maybe I have to consider 8 cases separately. The case when the arguments for all the absolute values are non-negative seems simple. Specifically, in that case we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{ \lvert a + b \rvert }{1 + \lvert a + b \rvert} &= \frac{ a + b }{1 + a + b }\\
&= \frac{a}{1 + a + b} + \frac{b}{1 + a + b}\\
&\leq \frac{a}{1 + a} + \frac{b}{1 + b}
\end{align*}

but I'm looking at some basic properties for ordered fields and I'm not even sure I can justify this result.

The next case I considered was $\lvert a + b \rvert = -(a + b), \lvert a \rvert = a, \lvert b \rvert = b$, but I don't think this is possible.

The third case I considered was  $\lvert a + b \rvert = -(a + b), \lvert a \rvert = -a, \lvert b \rvert = b$ but I don't know how to deal with this.

For $(b)$, I am lost. For $(c)$, I see that this is equivalent to $\lvert ab^{-1} + a^{-1}b \rvert \geq 2$. I was trying to use (ix) in the properties of fields from the text (picture below) but I don't know how to use it. I can't make the assumption that $a > b > 0$. I *could* assume that $\lvert a \rvert \geq \lvert b \rvert > 0$, and if I'm right, that would give me $\lvert a \rvert \lvert b \rvert ^{-1} \geq 1$, but I'm not even sure this approach would work, due to the triangle inequality issue.

I appreciate any help.

**Properties of fields:**

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Rule of thumb: (1) Prove those inequalities in $\mathbb R$. (2) See if anything in your proof doesn't work in an arbitrary ordered field.

Comment: Seems like reasonable advice. I will come back later and try to work in the reals.